# Error opening XML file in PHP with UTF-8

Tags: php, xml, encoding, utf-8

In my page, I try to open some xml files:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("users/" .$f->name."/data.xml");
```

The problem is that `$f->name` can include characters as vowels with accents, and because of that there´s an error when opening the file. For example, instead of García, it reads GarcÃ­a. How can I solve it? (I´ve already tried with `utf8_encode($f->name)`)

Comment: Is there any way you can create a more uniform file naming scheme? Without special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("users/" .rawurlencode($f->name)."/data.xml");
```